# Nginx rewrite rule dynamic sub-folders and path

Tags: linux, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a URL pattern to sub-folder.

```
location ~^ /test/article/(.*) {
    root /var/www/example.com/test;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;
}
```

When a user requests http://www.example.com/test/article/article-name, 
I need to rewrite the URL to http://www.example.com/test/, but URL should stay the same, it should display as http://www.example.com/test/article/article-name in the browser.

"article-name" could be any thing with dashes. But "article" is the hard coded path, not a real folder.

My server is currently hosting Wordress in root directory of Nginx server which is /var/www/example.com/ . I tried different things with Nginx config file and not working yet. Currently, when I typed in http://www.example.com/test/article/article-name , Wordpress will show 404 error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Updates:::::::
Here is my latest config file under sites-available folder. It's showing Wordpress's home page when I tried the URL.

```
server {


    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;

    port_in_redirect off;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1/32;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    rewrite ^/test/article/(.*) /test/;
    location /test/ {
        root /var/www/example.com/test/;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
        # serve static files directly
        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
              access_log        off;
              expires           max;
         }

         location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
         }


    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

}
```

Another update:
I am now testing with following config and it doesn't show Wordpress's 404 anymore. But it actually redirects to /test folder. I need to keep the url with "/test/article/article-name" in it.

```
rewrite ^/test/article/(.*) /test/;

location /test/ {
     index index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewrite ^/test/article/(.*) /test;

location /test {
    root /var/www/example.com/;
}
# create file `test` in `/var/www/example.com/`
```

Choice II

```
rewrite ^/test/article/(.*) /test/;

location /test/ {
    root /var/www/example.com/test/;
    index index.html;
}
# create directory `test` in `/var/www/example.com/`
# and create file `index.html` in `/var/www/example.com/test/`
```

Comment: I added those before any other "location" in the config file.  When I tried to visit http://www.example.com/test/article/article-name    Wordpress showed its home page. My config file is inside the "sites-available" folder with the domain name. In this case, file name is "example.com". Thanks!

Comment: I did the Choice II. and also created directory test and file index.html.  Still showing Wordpress's home page.

Comment: Larry, I added the whole config file in my question with your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Larry, Your suggestion is working (choice II). I found out that I was having issue because of my index.html. I can't select your answer since my reputation is low. Thank you.

Comment: I feel Choice II is better but did not work for me ...  is there any condition under which Choice II will not work